# Fetching data from a website to android app

Tags: java, asp.net, html, kotlin

Currently i have a website of my [institute](http://tcsc.org.in/attendanceChk/) ,I wish to develop an android app for the same to make it easier to the students to access the results which come after filling the details in the [**URL**](http://tcsc.org.in/attendanceChk/) , For reference you may select the details respectively in the form [**Stream**- Degree science; **Class**- F.Y.B.Sc; **Division**- CPM(A); **Roll no**- 1743 ] Also, Wanted to know if Json fetching and Parsing Data concept would work for this or not?
Answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hi, You can use a webview directly within your app to go to the results page. If not, you have to create a rest api service to send/receive data at runtime. JSon fetching and parsing is possible but how would you send the data to the page without the query string.

Comment: As @IshtdeepHora said, the **simplest way** is to use `WebView` and let your website do the job. But if you want your app to just concentrate on that task and give more flexibility, creating your own REST API and make your application connect to that service would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup is the good choice for your question. [Link here](https://jsoup.org/)

You should know about how to parse HTML to string by XML Query, CSS Query, ....

Step by step:

1. Build a connection to your website you want to parse.
2. prepare the query to get a "infomation" string in.
3. Put String to object and show it.

Below is my code to get a version code of my app in market googleplay using css query and JSOUP:

```
try {
    newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.example.myapp" + "&hl=en")
            .timeout(5000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .get()
            .select("div.hAyfc:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
            .first()
            .ownText();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```